# ADMOb not working

Tags: android, admob

Manifest file is

```
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Activity class has this -

```
        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxxx");
    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout02);
    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);
    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    new AdRequest().addTestDevice("CD9E4FDFA47A4AA03F9883E77C036EB3");
```

After running I get this -

```
05-17 22:39:11.153: INFO/Ads(7831): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"msid":"com.cob.fivethings","hl":"en","preqs":0,"u_so":"p","slotname":"a14dd24e71c7a34","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0","app_name":"1.android.com.cob.fivethings","isu":"CD9E4FDFA47A4AA03F9883E77C036EB3","u_audio":3,"u_w":320,"format":"320x50_mb","u_sd":1,"net":"ed","u_h":480});</script></head><body></body></html>
05-17 22:39:13.138: INFO/Ads(7831): Received ad url: <"url": "http://r.admob.com:80/ad_source.php?msid=com.cob.fivethings&hl=en&preqs=0&u_so=p&slotname=a14dd24e71c7a34&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0&app_name=1.android.com.cob.fivethings&isu=CD9E4FDFA47A4AA03F9883E77C036EB3&u_audio=3&u_w=320&format=320x50_mb&u_sd=1&net=ed&u_h=480&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=-60&ex=1&client_sdk=1", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
05-17 22:39:27.058: INFO/ActivityManager(1848): Stopping service: com.android.mms/.transaction.TransactionService
05-17 22:40:11.163: INFO/Ads(7831): AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the HTML.
05-17 22:40:11.193: INFO/Ads(7831): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
05-17 22:43:07.343: INFO/ActivityManager(1848): Stopping service: com.android.mms/.transaction.TransactionService
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Do you have the latest admob jar?

Comment: Is this on your phone or emulator?  Does it have internet connection?

Comment: I found this link on google group - [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/-63O0npCjL0) 
This explains why mine was not working. Apparantly on 1.5 Android phones and emulator it will not work. When I tried it on 1.6 it worked straightaway.

Comment: Got this over and over again on the simulators, for days on end that I struggled. Tried as I may I could not get it to work. Loaded the app to my Samsung Galaxy S, waited for at least a minute or so and Bob's your uncle, it worked.

Comment: If your admob account has just created, there will be some days delay for admob to give you impression. Its not your code problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the following from the "application" section of your manifest

```
        <!-- The application's publisher ID assigned by AdMob -->
    <meta-data android:value="xxxxxxxxxxx" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />

    <!-- AdMobActivity definition -->
    <activity android:name="com.admob.android.ads.AdMobActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" />
    <!-- Track Market installs -->          
    <receiver android:name="com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

My Android game was published on the Google's market, but I didn't get any impressions from AdMob. There was no significant changes in the code, or even changes at all that touched AdMob sources and the previous versions of my game were working properly.

As it turned out the problem was elevated during obfuscation process done by proguard. If you're using it to do the mangling of Java's symbols get rid of the `-optimize` directive from your proguard.cfg and put `-dontoptimize` instead.