# Admob on android 1.5 works or not?

Tags: android, admob

Has anyone ever been successfull in implementing admob on android 1.5?

I tried yesterday and it failed [see here pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037521/admob-not-working)

I got it working on android 1.6 without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change of class name?

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwhirl-users/c2MI_Kczjag